# How to search by data-test? (not data-testid)

Tags: react-testing-library

When I import screen object like this

`import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';`

it allows me to issue the following command: `screen.findByTestId(...)`, but how can I search by `data-test` (not `data-testid`)? Tried to search by custom attribute, but there was no `findByAttribute` method in `screen` either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you had a chance to see the the document?
https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-custom-queries/

If you want to query with your own-defined attribute, you can make one using `buildQueries`

```
// custom-queries.js

import {queryHelpers, buildQueries} from '@testing-library/react'

// query
const queryAllByData = (...args) =>
  queryHelpers.queryAllByAttribute('data-test', ...args)

const [
  queryByDataTest,
] = buildQueries(queryAllByData)

export {
  queryByDataTest
}
```

```
// test-utils.js

import {render, queries} from '@testing-library/react'
import * as customQueries from './custom-queries'

const customRender = (ui, options) =>
  render(ui, {queries: {...queries, ...customQueries}, ...options})

// re-export everything
export * from '@testing-library/react'

// override render method
export {customRender as render}
```

```
//test.spec.jsx

const {getByData} = render(<Component />)

expect(getByData('my-component')).toHaveTextContent('Hello')
```

You can find more in the attached document.

Answer (score 2):

While the accepted answer works, the recommended way to update the global `testIdAttribute` across tests is:

```
...
import { configure } from '@testing-library/react';
...

configure({ testIdAttribute: 'data-test' });
```

This way, you can continue using `screen.findByTestId(...)` without defining and maintaining any custom query. You can do this per test or globally per app on your global jest config using the `setupFilesAfterEnv`.

An example of this would look like this:

#### jest.config.ts

```
import type { Config } from 'jest';

const config: Config = {
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/jest-setup.ts'],
};

export default config;
```

#### jest-setup.ts

```
import { configure } from '@testing-library/dom';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';

configure({ testIdAttribute: 'data-test' });
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, you can use [Manual Queries](https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/about#manual-queries)

First, you need to get the container where the rendering was.
Then search inside of it by your attribute.

```
const {container} = render(<MyComponent />)
const foo = container.querySelector('[data-test="my-component"]')
```

But you should remember this approach contradicts the ideology of React Testing Library, which says User cannot navigate your application by attributes.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).